# Replace all items that are not belong to characters and numbers by ' '

Tags: shell, regular-expression

I want to replace all symbols like '.','-','/' and so on by ' '

I tried`sed 's/[[!:alnum:]]/ /g' example.txt` but it does not work

and for `sed 's/[,;\.\-\/()_]/ /g' example.txt`, I found that I cannot replace '-' by ' '.

is there any way to do that?

Comment: Perhaps the class you are looking for is `[[:punct:]]`? Regarding the use of `-` in character brackets, see [What is difference between \[-a-z\] and \[a-z\] in regular expression?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424977/what-is-difference-between-a-z-and-a-z-in-regular-expression)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match all non-alphanumerics, use `[^[:alnum:]]`. It's similar to `[^abc]`: the leading caret makes the bracket expression match all but the listed characters.

To match a literal dash, you need to make sure it's not interpreted as creating a list of characters to match. Make it the first character of the bracket expression: `[-,.;/()_]`.

Note that sed doesn't take the `/` as a separator for `s///` if it's within a bracket expression, so there's no need to put a backslash in front of it. (The backslash will match itself.) E.g. `echo 'a\b/c'  | sed 's/[/\]/./g'` prints `a.b.c`.

See for example the [`regex(7)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html) for a description of the regular expression syntax. (Note that it mainly discusses extended regular expressions (ERE), used by `sed -E` in many/most seds.)